# c++ queue memory leak

Tags: c++, memory-management, memory-leaks

I have a trouble with C++ code, lost memory somewhere in this part of code. 
I'm not good with C++, please help. I want to create queue of arrays, but there is some error in this code.

```
const size_t _queueSize;
size_t _queueBack;
size_t width;
size_t height;
u_char** _history;

....

    if (_queueBack) {
        for (int i = _queueBack; i > 0; --i) {
            _history[i] = _history[i-1];
        }
    }
    if (_queueSize == _queueBack) {
        delete[] _history[_queueSize + 1];
        _history[0] = new u_char [height*width];
    } else {
        ++_queueBack;
    }
```

P.S. I'm not able to use STL I need fast queue.

Comment: All those raw pointers are a recipe for disaster Have you bothered profiling the standard library queue before disqualifying it?

Comment: In light of "I'm not good with C++", I would reconsider "I'm not able to use STL I need fast queue". The chance that you will be able to implement a queue that's more efficient than a std::queue seem low to me.

Comment: No, I don't, but I'm sure that I need low level arrays. I process raw images, pixel by pixel, so I think STL will be unproductive.

Comment: You should try the standard library first, then, *iff* it proves to be too slow, figure out where the time is lost, and fix that particular problem.

Comment: You think that based on what? It's one thing to try the *std* containers and see they don't quite make the cut. It's another to assume it beforehand, especially given the "I'm not good with c++" remark.

Comment: At the very least, if you insist on avoiding containers, use some smart pointer class for RAII rather than chasing your memory.

Comment: I think, there are not a lot of people in whole world, who excellent with C++ =). I will try to use some stl container, but I still interest with low level solutions. Thanks all for yours comments.

Comment: Wishing you the best of luck in implementing a faster queue than the standard library on your platform, particularly in light of the second sentence in this post. And it isn't possible to answer your question as-posted regardless. there is no allocation in this code, so weighing whoever/however it is performed against the solitary `delete[]` in this is going to be... speculative. Please post a [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org) that *exhibits the problem* when-next you post, and I can all-but-guarantee you'll have answers rolling at you.

Comment: It's easier to make a correct program fast than to make a fast program correct.

Answer (score 0):

You can check your leaks using valgrind, the memory leak can be produce somewhere else in the code and "explode" in that point.

Btw, I strongly believe that you should use STL and if you need some kind of special requirement with memory implement you own allocator. I doubt you can a achieve a better solution than STL, that is one of the most common mistakes or legends people has, STL is not slow, it is the way you use it.

Comment: I'm developing for iOS, there are mix of C, C++ and Obj-C code. xcode analizer can't find any error. btw Obj-C containers was slow so I decided to use love level solution.

Comment: If it is for iOS you can not use Valgrind it doesn't work any longer :/. I dont really know if this is ok but `delete[] _history[_queueSize + 1];` this seems like wrong right? I mean, if your queue is of 10 elements you can not delete _history[10] or _history[11].

Comment: @Dmitriy you'd be surprised how fast `std::queue<std::vector<>>` will perform, particularly with emplacement and move-semantics. The clang 3.3 you're using is good, so give it a shot.